# Connect to SQL Server 2008 from C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ado.net, database-connection

I am having problem in login. i have made a database in SQL Server 2008. After attaching the data base when i run my software in visual studio 2010, the login of my software fails. it says

> Invalid user name or password"

while on my other PC the software is working fine.

i am not able to understand the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you have an invalid user name or password. Did you set up your login correctly? =D

Comment: please show the complete connection string you use, otherwise this is tough to diagnose.

Comment: Can you show us your connection strings and the code that connects? Also; are your local database permissions the same as what's running on the box you can connect to?

Comment: does ConnectionString ring any bells?

Answer (score 1):

If your credentials are fine, and connection strings are correct try swapping in sql server 2008 from windows authentication mode to sql mixed mode which is found in options, I believe under security.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your login information is invalid on your current PC, most likely because of the SQL security settings.

Perhaps it allows a trusted connection from your other computer, but not from this one.

The solution is to fix your SQL server settings. The easiest way would be to create an sql user name and give it the proper permissions, then connect to the server using this user name instead of a trusted connection or NT authorization. The last part requires you to add

```
;UserId=...;Password=...
```

to your connection string.